# How to simplify an async call inside a React useEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create the simplest React Hook `useEffect` call I can and hoping not to have to create a function call inside `useEffect`.  My code is below and it requires me to call `fetchData()` to make it work.   Is there a simpler version of this?

Maybe with a strategically placed async keyword or something like that?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
      let result = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/');
      console.log(result.data.length);
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Use the `then` block of the promise returned by axios: `useEffect(() => axios.get(...).then(result => console.log(result.data.length)), []);`

Comment: Interested to see others answers, but I dont think you can do async directly within useEffect.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir , Thanks for the answer. I may have simplified my question too much.  I have a cleanup function that is returned, and I don't want the cleanup function to run until after the axios async call completes. I'm not sure I'll get the same behavior if I use .then instead of await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is make it an IIFE:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const promise = (async () => {
      let result = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/');
      console.log(result.data.length);
  })();
  return (() => {
    promise.then(() => cleanup());
  });
}, []);
```

Or use plain promises:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const promise = axios.get('http://localhost:4000/').then((result) => {
      console.log(result.data.length);
  });
  return (() => {
    promise.then(() => cleanup());
  })
}, []);
```

But that is about as much as you can do since useEffect cannot be async directly. From ESLint:

> Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions.

Comment: Why not just call `cleanup` at the end of the `async` IIFE or at the end of `then`'s callback? as it won't get called untill the `await`ed call completes anyway

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The problem is that the cleanup should probably happen after unmounting, rather than directly after the request (although I might be misinterpreting the question at that point in which case you are right, the cleanup task should be run directly after await or the next then)

Comment: I want to be assured that the async call completed before cleanup is called.  Seems like with an IIFE or promise, that cleanup might happen before the async completes. (I'm not sure of this but worried)

Comment: @Pete, That is why I added the `promise.then(() => cleanup());`, since that will either wait until the request is complete or run immediately if it was completed already